# infinite scroll not working with ajax and real time components

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel-5, infinite-scroll

i was using

```
http://laraget.com/blog/implementing-infinite-scroll-pagination-using-laravel-and-jscroll
```

my script :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('ul.pagination').hide();
    $(function() {
        $('.infinite-scroll').jscroll({
            autoTrigger: true,
            loadingHtml: '<img class="center-block" id="loadsmall" style="width:80px; height:80px;" src="/" alt="Loading..." />',
            padding: 0,
            nextSelector: '.pagination li.active + li a',
            contentSelector: 'div.infinite-scroll',
            callback: function() {
                $('ul.pagination').remove();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

my view :

```
<div class="infinite-scroll">
    @foreach($comments as $comment)
        <h4 class="media-heading">{{ $comment->author_name }}
            <small>{{ $comment->created_at->diffForHumans() }}</small>
        </h4>
        {{ $comment->body }}
        <hr>
    @endforeach

    {{ $comments->links() }}
</div>
```

in my posts section i have applied it , all static part is working fine , but there is a ajax portion in which user can like a post .. the ajax portion is not working on the posts that come after the working of infinite scroll

Comment: Probably because the event listeners you attach on page load are not attached to the content which is appended on scroll.

Comment: then should i use ajax instead of jquery?

Comment: if you are aware of any good ..ajax method for infinite scroll let me know..just need to get a little idea about it..:)